# Only English output from Windows command line tools

Tags: windows

My windows application tries to parse the command result of command line tools and it works well in English language pack.
However, I was wondering if when customer is using a different language pack so if the result of the command is in Japanese/Chinese/Korean, I think I should modify the parsing logic accordingly. 
I think this approach doesn't seem to be a right direction.

Is there any way to force English output ?

Comment: What exactly do you do ? Call a program and parse its output ? This is language pack and / or locale specific. Show us your code. And try to replace the external call with an APIs call

Comment: For instance, my app uses a windows shell and to create a windows service, it should run ' sc.exe create ..... '. If it succeeds, the shell result would be like ' [SC] CreateService Success' in English pack. However, if user uses other language pack, the result will be like '[SC] CreateService ####' #### denotes other language. I'm looking for the way I can only get the English result/output in Ms-Dos. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are not talking to MS-DOS because this is its own operating system. Windows no longer is build on a DOS base, the last versions that did so were Windows 95 and 98 I think.

You are calling command line commands / executables of Windows and they can't be forced to use all English. Perhaps you can interpret the return code and detect an error this way. Some tools can be forced to return csv (wmic for example) but I don't think sc can be.

My suggestion is that you search SO for a solution how to call the CreateService from your programming language.

Comment: That's what I wanted to check. "can't be forced to use all English". Okay. I think I should parse the each language output. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sigularity My recommendation still is to use an APIs, this would even enable you to take care of uac and get the necessary permissions for installing the service. And you are always welcome to modify your question in order to remove misleading information / tags. Have a look at my edit.